# Would a time-revering (or phase conjugate) mirror make a good light sail?

Tags: visible-light, solar-sails

In hard science fiction and speculative essays, we hear of light sails being driven by home-based lasers.

Would a [*time reversal* mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_optics#Optical_phase_conjugation) make a more efficent sail? I’m thinking that the light (and energy) could be recirculated to continue to power the laser. That is, the beam once generated with an initial power cost would bounce back and forth between the stationary emitter and the driven sail, imparting momentum on each bounce.

Comment: It would be too heavy.

Comment: @mmesser314 if it’s heavier by a factor of n, then after n round-trip bounces of the photons you come out ahead in terms of the energy needed to propel the craft.  So you need to be more quantitative to make a valid argument against.